# Error while accessing property file by ResourceBundle

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml, resourcebundle

I can not access property file from main method.

I have added property file under src/main/java , its working if i run the main class in Eclipse but its not working in command prompt if i use this command

```
mvn -e exec:java  -Dexec.mainClass=tenkinfo.toolUtils.BalancingFinancials
```

> static ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("utils");
>
> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on
>   project ToolUtils: An exception occured while executing the Java
>   class. null: ExceptionInInitializerError: Can't find bundle for base
>   name utils, locale en_IN -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java
>   (default-cli) on project ToolUtils: An exception occured while
>   executing the Java class. null
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured
>   while executing the Java class. null
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute (ExecJavaMojo.java:339)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject
>   (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build
>   (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced
>   (Launcher.java:289)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode
>   (Launcher.java:415)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356) Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:835) Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find bundle for base name
>   utils, locale en_IN
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.throwMissingResourceException (ResourceBundle.java:2055)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl (ResourceBundle.java:1689)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl (ResourceBundle.java:1593)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundleImpl (ResourceBundle.java:1556)
>       at java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle (ResourceBundle.java:857)
>       at tenkinfo.toolUtils.BalancingFinancials. (BalancingFinancials.java:38)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:567)
>       at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:835)[image]

Comment: Open the target folder and check if this file is present in it.

Answer (score 0):

`ResourceBundle` class is for Locale i think you want to just use regular properties, which should be located in `/src/main/resources/`

Take a look at https://crunchify.com/java-properties-file-how-to-read-config-properties-values-in-java/